# Python selenium : Explicitly wait for one of two elements to be loaded

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way using which I can wait for one of two elements to get loaded in selenium. I am using explicit waits and so far, haven't been able to figure out the solution.

Simply doing

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element(By.ID,"a") or driver.find_element(By.ID,"b"))
```

doesn't seem to work. It just looks for element with id ="a".

Thanks!

Comment: Just load the page and put a test for the element you want inside a "`while True`" loop waiting for half a second each cycle.

Comment: How about generating an XPATH that hits both targets? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73226676/single-xpath-to-encompass-two-different-object-structures

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`find_element` raises `NoSuchElementException` exception if no element is found.

If element with the id `a` does not exist, `driver.find_element(By.ID,"a")` will raises the exception and the `driver.find_element(By.ID,"b")` will not be executed.

A simple way to solve the problem is using `find_elements` which return empty list instead of raising the exception:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_elements(By.ID,"a") or driver.find_elements(By.ID,"b"))
```

Comment: It cleared my concept of lambda- `until` waits for a true case.

Answer (score 7):

As falsetru [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27606503/1906307) if your first `find_element` call fails to find an element, it will raise `NoSuchElementException` and the 2nd part of your test won't execute.

I would suggest using a CSS selector that matches either IDs you are looking for:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#a, #b"))
```

This has an advantage over performing two `find_elements` calls becayse this will make only one roundtrip between your Selenium client (your script) and the Selenium server. This should always be faster than performing two `find_elements` calls. When performing tests locally, the difference won't be much but if you perform tests remotely, for instance using Sauce Labs or Browser Stack, the difference will be significant.

Answer (score -1):

Note, find_elements returns a list, so if you wanted to test for the element you will have to iterate through a list
So in the below code I needed to test for 2 elements (depending on the scenario) and then test what element was returned so I can do the apropriate action

```
# If the number is NOT a WhatsApp number then there will be an OK Button, not the Message Textbox
            # Test for both situations -> find_elements returns a List
            ctrl_element = self.wait.until(
                lambda ctrl_self:
                    ctrl_self.find_elements(By.XPATH, nr_not_found_xpath) or
                    ctrl_self.find_elements(By.XPATH, inp_xpath)
            )
            # Iterate through the list of elements to test each if they are a textBox or a Button
            for i in ctrl_element:
                if i.aria_role == 'textbox':
                    # This is a WhatsApp Number -> Send Message
                    i.send_keys(message + Keys.ENTER)
                    msg = f"Message sent successfully to {self.mobile}"

                elif i.aria_role == 'button':
                    # This is NOT a WhatsApp Number -> Press enter and continue
                    i.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                    msg = f"Not a WhatsApp Number {self.mobile}"
```