# Xpath to encompass two different object structures

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm automating with Selenium. I'm dealing with 2 variants (mobile, desktop) of a page. Both have a "Login" button, but the HTML is different.

First variant:

```html
 <div role="button"><div ...><span><span>Foo Bar MaybeQuux</span></span></div></div>
```

Second variant:

```html
<a href="p/q/r" data="loginButton"><div><span><span>Foo Bar MaybeQuux</span></span></div></a>
```

I've written `MaybeQuux` as for small screens it turns into `Mayb...`. However `Bar` is guaranteed.

Here's my code so far:

```py
def waitClickable(by, text, timeout=60):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (by, text)
        )
    )

waitClickable(By.XPATH, "???").click()
```

So my question is, would it possible to write a single xpath that can locate both variants?

If so I can avoid the awkwardness of having to wait on an object of unknown form.

ref: [Python selenium : Explicitly wait for one of two elements to be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606026/python-selenium-explicitly-wait-for-one-of-two-elements-to-be-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering both the HTMLs:

- First:

  ```
  <div role="button"><div ...><span><span>Foo Bar MaybeQuux</span></span></div></div>
  ```
- Second:

  ```
  <a href="p/q/r" data="loginButton"><div><span><span>Foo Bar MaybeQuux</span></span></div></a>
  ```

Both have the following identical features:

- *`Bar`* is the guaranteed text
- *`Mayb`* is the guaranteed text
- The above texts are within a `<span>`
- The grandchild `<span>` is within it's immediate parent `<span>`
- The parent `<span>` is within it's immediate parent `<div>`

---

### Solution

A common [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) to both the elements would be:

```
//div/span/span[contains(., 'Bar') and contains(., 'Mayb')]
```

---

### POC

[image: Maybe]

Answer (score 1):

This XPath should get the inner `span` in both cases

`'//div[@role="button"]/descendant::span[starts-with(.,"Foo Bar")] | //a[@data="loginButton"]/descendant::span[starts-with(.,"Foo Bar")]'`

Alternative expressions

`//*[(name()="div" and @role="button") or (name()="a" and @data="loginButton")]/descendant::span[starts-with(.,"Foo Bar")]`

`//*[(self::div and @role="button") or (self::a and @data="loginButton")]/descendant::span[starts-with(.,"Foo Bar")]`

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if this would serve as an answer to the referenced question also. Nobody seems to have come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below XPATH

```
//*[self::div[@role='button'] or self::a[@data='loginButton'] and starts-with(.//span, 'Foo Bar Maybe')]
```

but the easiest way is

```
//span[starts-with(., 'Foo Bar Mayb')]
```

or

```
//span[contains(., 'Bar Mayb')]/ancestor::*[self::a[@data='loginButton'] or self::div[@role='button']]
```

Comment: Could you break the syntax down a little? Usually I can figure syntax out if I know what the thing does, but I'm struggling with XPATHs. Those last examples... they aren't reaching back to their containing `a`/`div`s. Can I get selenium to click the span and it will click the button?

Comment: @Pi if click on `span` doesn't work and you want XPath to return `a` or `div` tru `//span[contains(., 'Bar Mayb')]/ancestor::*[self::a[@data='loginButton'] or self::div[@role='button']]`